# How does setOnclickListner(this) work?

Tags: android, this

There are multiple ways to register callbacks when a Button is clicked. If I go by the following way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello onCLick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I don't understand how the method setOnClickListener(this) identifies that  it should call onClick() method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "this" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921167/what-does-this-mean)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/17964932/1234007

Comment: I don't get it. Why a downvote?
They are different answers, might be that understanding them leads to the same conclusion.
My question is - "how the method setOnClickListener(this) identifies that it should call onClick() method?"
Please read it carefully!

Comment: @Mooooooo Please do me a favor and go about downvoting all questions on this site.

Comment: @Mooooooo I thought you downvoted my question, which now I'm assuming you didn't! Peace! :)

Answer (score 2):

This refers to the activity. Because the Activity implements an OnClickListener calling button.setOnClickListener(this) gives the onClickListener that the Activity implements to setOnClickListener.

I recommend you look up info about implementing interfaces in Java if you want tot know more about this practise.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your confusion. When you read other SO answers or references like the [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html), it feels like all the sentences are telling the same thing but nothing that really helps *click*.

What happens is, when a `Button` is clicked, it will *notify* all the objects that are listenning for it. You are subscribing your activity as a listener, to this event with the line

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

So, on an event of a click, button knows that it should call the activity's `onClick` event.

> I don't understand how the method `setOnClickListener(this)` identifies
>   that it should call `onClick()` method?

(Therefore, it s the **button** that calls the `listener.onClick()` method, in case there's a confusion there.)

Also, @nourikhalass has a point, you should first make sure that interfaces make sense to you.

Is it any clearer?

Answer (score 1):

if you are aware about oops 'this' refer the reference of current object of class. a good explanation is define [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword)

In above case MainActivity reference is refer as this here.

`public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l)`

is setter method define in class Button which hold the reference on "OnClickListener".

when you set setOnClickListener(this) it define you are passing OnClickListener reference as your activity so to make your activity as type on OnClickListener you have to implement the interface OnClickListener in your activity class as it is showing in your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Its a callback listener which have method "onClick" you have to override that method
 and when button is clicked that method is call by Button class so the event listener (which is you activity in current scenario) can listen to it.

Comment: Brother, +1 for the link, but your command on English Language - facepalm

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Its very generous you point out my mistake .I will try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has

```
MainActivity implements OnClickListener
```

but actually it is:

```
MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Maybe that is what confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

"This" refers to current object.

To handle button clicks, an object must implement the "OnClickListener" interface and define what to do when clicks are received in "onClick" method. Then you can register that object as a listener for your button clicks.

In your case, your activity implements OnClickListener, and onClick shows a toast:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello onCLick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Therefore, your activity can handle button clicks, so you register it as a listener for your button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

As "this" implements the required interface, is a valid listener.