# OnClickListener for child views when parent itself has OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I just experimented with setting an `OnClickListener` to a parent `View` and  an `OnClickListener` for every children. Without the children listener the parent listener would fire at any point in the layout but when I added children listeners only the listener associated with the child at that position fired. Is this the expected behavior? Where is this documented?

Comment: What is your question ? Events gets handles in a hierarchy where Child gets the priority (if set).

Comment: @ADM My question is where is that documented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do android's Event Listeners work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964835/how-do-androids-event-listeners-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an hierarchy of views starting with a parent view, a click event is *"absorbed"* by the 1st visible and enabled view (at the lower level) positioned at the physical area of the click event that has **a registered listener**. 
Of course if needed, the invoked listener of that view may (or may not) trigger the click event of other views in the hierarchy but this is not the usual practice. 
For documentation, you may read this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events

especially the section **"Event handlers"**, where there are mentioned ways for changing the above described default way of handling input events.